# Unallocated space partition to Primary Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

My dilemma is a little different than some of the other scenarios involving partitioning setups.

I have 442GB unallocated space between sda3(NTFS) and the Ubuntu partitions and want to assign this unallocated space to sda6, which is the root ext4 partition. Problem is that the three Ubuntu partitions are all primary.

How to do this in GParted? (or are there multiple ways to deal with this)

[image]

Comment: I created separate EFI partitions and boot through BIOS as I don't have Grub installed. I use Systemd's bootloader and copied the Windows EFI folder over to the other EFI.

Comment: Just curious... why don't you use GRUB? You can directly boot either OS from the GRUB menu.

Comment: Do a `free -h` command and confirm that it shows your 8G swap.

Comment: @ heynnema Oh, the reason for this is that I am using a downstream distro (Pop!_OS) and they don't actually use GRUB. I spoke to the dev who told me their reasons for it, basically amounting to that Systemd has its own bootloader and am guessing to they don't want the added support requests when GRUB breaks (they actually recommend booting from firmware). Systemd was pretty good at automatically detecting my copied MS EFI folder in /boot/efi.

Comment: So, inquiring minds want to know... please explain exactly what you had to do to prepare to boot this way, and what steps you actually have to do to boot one OS or the other. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema I followed these steps, essentially mounting the Windows EFI using a gui disks tool, then copying the MS folder over: https://pop-planet.info/forums/threads/copy-the-microsoft-bootloader-into-pops-efi-beginners-guide.357/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** sda4 partition all the way left
- **move** sda5 partition all the way left
- **move** sda6 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of sda6 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Comment: Thanks! One more question that this raised was in the first instruction: "always start the entire procedure with issuing a swapoff on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a swapon on that same swap partition".  How would I do that - by when in term with sudo swapoff -a and then right-click,  'swapon'  in GParted?

Comment: @KennyHeimbuch Both the swapoff and swapon commands can be done directly from within `gparted`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @ heynnema I did the checkmark, but since I am a new user it doesn't register my upvote on the up-arrow icons. Many thanks again for your answer.

Comment: You don't need to move `sda6` to the left before resize. You can resize to the left by dragging the left edge of `sda6`. At least that's how I remember it.

Comment: @user68186 You're correct, but I believe that the risks of corruption are higher that way. That's why I always move the partition first, and resize from the right.

Comment: Okay. i can't prove or disprove the higher risk of corruption claim. Personally I feel "safer" hitting the Apply button after each step rather than at the end. If something goes wrong while "applying" I think chances of having a working system is higher if I apply at each stage rather than at the end.

Comment: @user68186 Hitting the Apply button after each step may be safer, but unnecessary IMHO :-) Unless you have a power failure in the middle of things, and then you're screwed. Waiting until the end to do the Apply also gives you a chance to review the final configuration, and make sure it's really what you wanted, before the Apply. Also note that this particular user's partitions that get moved are small, so the total time to do it amounts to nothing. The OP did it my way and survived :-)

Comment: Fair enough! :-)